# Converting decision tree into a logical expression

Tags: discrete-mathematics, decision-trees

[image]

I need to convert this decision tree into a logical expression by using "and", "or" and "not" logical operators. I have been trying to solve this for 3 days. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Possible "0" indicates a query that is false and "1" a query that is true in your "decision tree".  If you "have been trying to solve this for 3 days", you should share something about your attempts when asking Readers to help.

Comment: Firstly, yes, 0 is false, 1 is true. People, who have enough knowledge to solve this, can know this already. Secondly, this is a binary decision diagram. Since "I have been trying to solve this for 3 days" I know solution way of this problem is the same for both decision tree and binary decision diagram. Since binary decision diagram was not on the tag list, I tagged decision tree. Lastly, I already took photos of my attemps, but since I am a new user, I cannot add photos. I can post just links. If I added these links, this topic would be full of links. I thought doing this would be unneeded.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume $0$ means False and $1$ means true.

Look at the leaves, see whether there are more $0$ or $1$. I will pick the one with less leaves.

There are two leaves with value $0$. One path is $F=0, H=1, J=0$. The other path is $F=1, G=0, K=0$.

\begin{align}&\neg \left( \left( \neg F \wedge H \wedge \neg J\right) \vee \left( F \wedge \neg G \wedge \neg K \right) \right) \\&=(F \vee \neg H \vee J) \wedge (\neg F \vee G \vee K)\end{align}

Comment: What is the purpose of the first "not" ? The one that is placed to outside of all the parentheses. Is it because of we picked 0 ?

Comment: Yes,  we negate everything since we picked $0$.

Comment: I tried to solve some problems about this topic and it was good. Thank you !

Comment: you're welcome.

Answer (score 1):

It's
$$(\neg F \wedge \neg H) \vee (\neg F \wedge H \wedge J) \vee (F \wedge G) \vee (F \wedge \neg G \wedge K)$$

(Here '$\wedge$' means 'and', '$\vee$' means 'or' and '$\neg$' means 'not'.)

Comment: Try to see how I derived it and check whether I made any mistakes. All you need to do is to follow the branches of the tree, concatenate the nodes along them (keeping track of the respective negations) and then form a disjunction of all of that.

Comment: I understand how you derived the (¬F∧¬H) and (F∧G).  The problem is, why we are not instered in J and K nodes ? For (¬F∧H∧J) and (F∧¬G∧K), we just wrote J and K. What about ¬J and ¬K ?

Comment: @E.Şakar We are only interested in branches that evaluate to true. All other expressions will then be false - by default. (Well, actually by how propositional logic is defined.)

Comment: Now, I know two ways to solve this kind of problems thanks to you. I appreciate you for your helpful explanations :)

Comment: You're very welcome :-)